# Triangle Similarity Problem with an inscribed right triangle in another triangle

Tags: geometry

Note: I am not very good at Latex so my question isn't really formatted.

Picture: [image]

I need to find $\bar{NO}$. First I thought that $\bar{NO}$ might be a midsegment so I tried to prove that. However, after messing around with the math and finding a few measures, I concluded that probably wasn't the solution to the problem.

Then, I looked at the problem and found out that $\triangle{NOM}$ is a 45-45-90 triangle so if I can find $\bar{NM}$ or $\bar{OM}$, I can find out $\bar{NO}$. However, this proved to be troublesome. By the Triangle Proportionality Theorem, $\frac{\bar{BN}}{\bar{NA}} = \frac{\bar{BO}}{\bar{OC}}$ so $\triangle{ABC}$ is similar to $\triangle{NBO}$ so now I know that $\frac{\bar{NO}}{\bar{AC}}=\frac{\bar{BN}}{\bar{NA}}=\frac{\bar{BO}}{\bar{OC}}$ so $\frac{NO}{30}=\frac{\bar{BN}}{\bar{NA}}=\frac{\bar{BO}}{\bar{OC}}$. Then I came to another dead end. I am not really sure how to continue, so if someone can help, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triangles $BNO$ and $BAC$ are similar, and altitude of $BNO$ relative to $NO$ is 
$\displaystyle10-{NO\over2}$.

Therefore you can find $NO$ with a simple proportion:
$$
NO:30=\left(10-{NO\over2}\right):10.
$$

Comment: How did you get the altitude of $BNO$ as $10-NO/2$?

Comment: The altitude of $MNO$ relative to $NO$ is $NO/2$ (isosceles right triangle).